# Time Derivative Under Integral Sign

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I've been banging my head recently with a doubt concerning the application of the Leibniz Integral Rule. Suppose you have a function of $x$ and $t$, $\phi (x,t)$, and that you have a certain quantity $L$, which is given by
$$
L = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\phi (x,t)dx
$$
According to the Leibniz Integral Rule, if I wanted to compute the time derivative of $L$ at some $t$, then
$$
\frac{dL}{dt} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} dx
$$
Thats all nice and good. But now suppose further that $L$ satisfies
$$
\frac{dL}{dt} = 0
$$
for all $t$. Is it valid then to say that the integrand must satisfy
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0
$$
for all $t$? I'll appreciate any help; I honestly feel like I'm drowning in a glass of water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As a counterexample, take $\phi=t\cos x$ so $\partial_t\phi=\cos x$.

Comment: An additional question, if i may ask: if $\phi$ were of the form $\phi = f \cdot g$, would the above imply that $\partial _{t} f \cdot g = -\partial _{t}g \cdot f $? I mean, because $D_{t} \int f \cdot g = \int \partial _{t} (f\cdot g ) = 0 $ would imply $\int \partial _{t}f \cdot g + \partial _{t}g \cdot f = 0$, right?

Comment: @SamuelAlonso Each of your conjectures boils down to assuming a function obtained by $\partial_t$ vanishes if its $\int_0^{2\pi}dx$ integral does, which doesn't even work for functions of $x$ alone. My counterexample already answers your second question: take $f=t,\,g=\cos x$.

Comment: Does this mean that two definite integrals over the same interval that share the same value don't necessarily imply the *integrands* are equal?

Comment: @SamuelAlonso Yes, that observation is equivalent to non-vanishing functions often integrating to $0$. Indeed, if two linearly independent functions integrate to nonzero finite values, a suitable linear combination of them achieves this.